# What are the features that are only available in Wolfram Finance Platform?

Tags: finance

Looking at the Wolfram Finance Platform [advertising page](http://www.wolfram.com/finance-platform/features/ultimate-financial-computation.html).

They seem to have features that are all available in standard *Mathematica* license. So what is the exact difference between the two? Their marketing page seems to be targeting people who don't know anything about *Mathematica*.

With *Mathematica* 12 they have updated the guide page `guide/ListingOfSupportedExternalServices` to display additional services that come with Wolfram Finance Platform, which are as follows:

- "BloombergTerminal" - access to real-time Bloomberg Terminal data (Windows only)
- "BloombergDataLicense" - access to stored Bloomberg Data License data (all platforms)
- "Reuters" - access to real-time Reuters data (Windows and Linux only)

Anyone that has used or is currently using Wolfram Finance Platform, please share what are the additional features apart from the extra `ServiceConnect`'s services and perhaps a more permissive commercial license?

Looking at the installer [here](https://support.wolfram.com/8046), we can see it is just Mathematica with two additional components:

- BloombergLink
- CUDA Acceleration for Financial Derivatives.

I wonder what edition of Mathematica is bundled in the Wolfram Finance Platform. Is it the Enterprise or Professional or Home edition?

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it, but the primary features that distinguish the Wolfram Finance Platform from *Mathematica* are:

- built-in support for Bloomberg/TR
- CUDA, more parallelization, and other HPC methods for trading
- report generation/delivery

Comment: Could you add citations for these? The report generation exists in plain Mathematica as well as some amount of CUDA support. My assumption was always that the Finance Platform was one of many partial rebrands of Mathematica with a slightly different focus so as to make it slightly easier for a specific group of people to use. Overall shouldn't truly be any different.

Comment: I think they should make documentation pages same for all varients of Mathematica but grey out the features that are not available under current version or license but make the full documentation still accessable. In that way every user of Mathematica will know about the features that are not available in his/her version. I will even say documentation should auto update to latest version but grey out the unavailable features. So 11.3 docs will show 12.0 features but greyed out.

Comment: @user, have you already sent this suggestion of yours to Support?

Comment: @J.M. No I haven't but feel free to send it if you want. Although I did mention in the comments of one of the live streams.